Absoluteness of "$z$ is an ordered pair" (as in Kunen).
I am trying to prove that (among others) "$z$" is an ordered pair" is absolute for any transitive model $\mathbf{M}$ of $\sf{ZF}^{-} - \sf{P}-\sf{Inf}$. Now, my reasonning is directly inspired by Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs".
The idea is to use lemma 3.10 in Kunen (p. 121) which says (loosely paraphrased):

Lemma 3.10: Absolute notions are closed under composition; that is, suppose $\mathbf{M} \subset \mathbf{N}$, $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n),F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $G(y_1,\ldots,y_m) \quad (i = 1,\ldots,n)$ are all absolute; then so are the formula $$\phi(G_1(y_1,\ldots,y_m),\ldots,G_n(y_1,\ldots,y_m))$$ (note that in Kunen, it says $G_1(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ here, but I think this is a typo). Furthermore, the function $$F(G_1(y_1,\ldots,y_m),\ldots,G_n(y_1,\ldots,y_m))$$ is absolute.

We are given $$\text{$z$ is an ordered pair} \leftrightarrow [\exists x \in \bigcup z \ \exists y \in \bigcup z(z = \langle x,y \rangle)].$$
We then write $$\text{$z$ is an ordered pair} \leftrightarrow \phi(G_1(z),G_2(z),G_3(z))$$ where \begin{align*} G_1(z) &= G_2(z)\\
&= \bigcup z \end{align*} which has been shown to be absolute (see lemma $3.9.(m)$). Let $G_3(z) = z$ and let $\phi(a,b,c)$ be $$\exists x \in a \ \exists y \in b(c = \langle x,y \rangle).$$
My question: Now, Kunen claims this is absolute since it is obtained by bounded quantification of the absolute formula $c = \langle x,y \rangle$. Now, I tried to show that this elementary formula is absolute:
We know that $x = y$ is absolute by lemma $3.9$.(a), and we know that $\langle x,y \rangle$ is absolute by $3.9.(f)$. So if we let $\psi(c,b)$ be $c = b$ and we let $G_1(y_1,y_2) \equiv c$ and $G_2(x,y) = \langle x,y \rangle$, then we see that $\psi(G_1(x,y),G_2(x,y))$ is $c = \langle x,y \rangle$. But I am having trouble conceptualizing if I have choosen $G_1(y_1,y_2) \equiv c$ correctly here. Is this absolute? If it is, it will follow that the composition is absolute by lemma $3.10$. And then by repeated application of lemma $3.4$ (twice) I think we see that $\exists x \in a \ \exists y \in b(c = \langle x,y \rangle)$ is absolute. Then one instance of lemma $3.10$ gives us that $\phi(G_1(z),G_2(z),G_3(z))$ is absolute, which was our original expression.
So my main problem is: how to conceptualize $G_1(y_1,y_2) \equiv c$?

“We know that $\langle x,y\rangle$ is absolute by 3.9 (f)”. How is that different from what you’re trying to show?

@spaceisdarkgreen Let me rephrase the prelude.
Well, no actually, hm, I am unsure, but this is directly from Kunen, so I don't think it's exactly the same; I mean "$z$ is an ordered pair" is not the same as $\langle x,y \rangle$, naively, I don't think; I could be wrong.

I'm referring to the "My question" part. You say you're trying to show $c=\langle x,y\rangle$ is an absolute formula. I don't have the book in front of me right now, but I don't know what "$\langle x,y\rangle$ is absolute" means, except for exactly that.

@spaceisdarkgreen It seems like you are equating $c = \langle x,y \rangle$ with just the expression $\langle x,y \rangle$, which I don't.

What is the definition of "$\langle x,y\rangle$ is absolute", then? (There is certainly a difference between the formula $c = \langle x,y\rangle$ and the expression $\langle x,y\rangle$... I'm just not sure what the difference between saying one or the other is absolute since in my view, saying the expression is absolute is certainly equivalent, if not definitionally the same, as saying the formula is absolute.)

We know that (kuratowskis definition) $\langle x,y \rangle = {{x},{x,y}}$.
Kunen writes \begin{align*} z &= \langle x,y\rangle\ &\leftrightarrow [\exists w \in z(w = {x}) \land \exists w \in z(w = {x,y}) \land \forall w \in z(w = {x} \lor w = {x,y})] \end{align*} and then one can show that the last formula above is logically equivalent to a $\Delta_0$ formula (so absolute, right)?

I mean, sure, you might well be correct. I am mainly trying to understand every detail of the proof (even things Kunen does not cover), to test my understanding. So I wanted to rewrite $c = \langle x,y \rangle$ on a form so that I could apply lemma $3.10$, but then I got stuck on how to choose $G_1(y_1,y_2)$ (note; the $G_1(y_1,y_2)$ used inside $\psi(b,c)$).

I see, my point was just that you seemed to be using what you were trying to prove in the proof. Yes, it makes sense to unpack that formula and show that it is $\Delta_0.$

Well, I am trying to find absolute (with respect to transitive classes $\mathbf{M}$) relations/functions whose composition gives me $c = \langle x,y \rangle$. I am unsure whether "$\phi$ absolute" $\iff$ "$\phi$ is  $\Delta_0$" is true (even for transitive $\mathbf{M})$.
By corollary IV 3.6 in Kunen we know that if $\mathbf{M}$ is transitive and $\phi$ is $\Delta_0 \implies$ $\phi$ is absolute for $\mathbf{M}$. I am unsure about the other direction.

Oh, my bad, of course it holds. This is exactly what we show in lemma $3.9.(f)$, as you pointed out earlier.

$\Delta_0$ implies absolute (for transitive sets/classes) but not the other way around. But yes,  $c = \langle x,y\rangle$ is $\Delta_0.$

Yes sorry, I should add that my last comment was about $c = \langle x,y \rangle$ holding due to what you pointed out earlier (this is exactly what we proved in $3.9.(f)$!); not the other direction with regards to $\Delta_0$ and absoluteness.

I am still unsure exactly why $G_1(z) = z$ is an absolute formula for transitive $\mathbf{M}$ though, perhaps this is the same obstruction to my understanding as why I had trouble with $G_1(y_1,y_2) \equiv c$.

Correction: $G_3(z) = z$.

I'm not understanding... are you asking why is the identity function absolute? What is "the formula $G_3(z) = z$"?

Yes, it should be absolute function. Definition $3.8$ gives us that if $\mathbf{M} \subset \mathbf{N}$ and $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a defined function, we say that $F$ is absolute for $\mathbf{M},\mathbf{N}$ if the formula $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = y$ holds.
But we only discuss absoluteness for $\mathbf{M},\mathbf{N}$ if we know that the statement $\forall x_1,\ldots,x_n \ \exists! y \ \phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y)$ is true in both $\mathbf{M},\mathbf{N}$.
So if $G_1(z) = z$, then what is the formula $\phi(x_1,y)$? Is it $\phi(x_1,y)$ as $x_1 = y$? In that case, since $x_1 = y$ is absolute is $G_1(z)$.

Yes, that's right. The identity function is defined by the formula $\phi(x,y) := x=y$, (and $\forall x \exists !y ;x=y$ holds, relative to anything) and so since $x=y$ is absolute, the identity function is absolute.

thanks =). Hm, I am similarly curious what $\phi(x_1,y)$ is for \begin{align*} G_1(z) &= G_2(z)\ \bigcup z. \end{align*} I suppose that, unabbreviated, it is $\phi(x_1,z)$ as $z = \bigcup x_1$? Then this ensures that $x_1$ is unique since $\mathbf{M}$ models extensionality (unless I am mistaken). Note that $\phi(x_1,z)$ as  $x_1 = \bigcup z$ would not work since $\bigcup {2}$ and $\bigcup {2,2}$ yield the same $x_1$, so $\neg \exists! y \phi(x_1,z)$ then.

Yes, though I think you meant abbreviated, not unabbreviated (in the sense that $z=\cup x_1$ is an abbreviation for what you get when you substitute the formula for what union means).

Ops, yes, abbreviated*.
